# How to split three column using linear layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

Can anybody tell me how to split three column using linear layout in Android?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Demonstratesahorizontallinearlayoutwithequallysizedcolumns.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

see first example, split in 3 instead of 4.

Answer (score 7):

Simple, just add `android:layout_weight="1"` to all of the children. That's the simple version, unless you want to do something more complicated, of course.